# How to fix this error "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:\frontend\passenger.blade.php)"

Tags: php, laravel

Here I'm trying to book my seat and I choose a seat and I tried to show that seat no into the next page value field but getting this error. If I insert the default value it's working. also, I can't able to insert those data into the database if set default value it works fine.

**passenger.blade.php:**

```
@foreach($seat_data as $key => $no)
    <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="rows">
        <div class="col-md-3"><strong>Seat No :{{$no['name']}} </strong></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="seat[{{$key}}]" class="form-control" id="validationDefault02" placeholder="Seat No" value="{{$no['name']}}">

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            {{--<label for="validationDefault01">Name</label>--}}
            <input type="text" name="name[{{$key}}]" class="form-control" id="validationDefault01" placeholder="First name">
        </div>
```

**PassengersController:**

```
public function collectInformation(Request $request)
{
    $buses_id = $request->buses_id;
    $schedules_id = $request->schedules_id;
    $seat_no = $request->seat_id;
    $data = Buses::where('buses_id', $buses_id)->first();
    $seat = json_decode($data->seat_layout, true);
    $count = count($seat_no);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $first = array_shift($seat_no);
        $name = empty($seat[$first]['name']) ? $seat[$first]['name'] : $seat_no;
        $seat_data[$i] = [
            'name' => $name,
            'id' => $seat_no,
        ];
    }
```

I changed my code like this it is working. Is that correct? but the problem is I can able to book the same seat again. The problem is in my changed code?

```
$seat_data[$i] = [ 
    'name' => $seat[$first]['name'], 
    'id' => $seat[$first]['id'], ];
```

Comment: Can you please share the data format of $seat_data ? it will make us easy to find the solution for you.

Comment: in my previous case @user3837868, try to look if there are empty fields/columns being retrieved by your variable "$seat_data" variable, because it you can't use the **htmlspecialchars** function if it's empty

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati longtext [{"style":"position: relative;","id":0,"name":"A1","profile":""},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in that line

```
$name = empty($seat[$first]['name']) ? $seat[$first]['name'] : $seat_no;
```

as we see here:

```
 $first = array_shift($seat_no);
```

`$seat_no` is an array, so `$name` would be either string `$seat[$first]['name']` or array `$seat_no`, when it is an array you get an error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string.."

I think you should think about and fix this line

```
$name = empty($seat[$first]['name']) ? $seat[$first]['name'] : $seat_no;
```

this is little bit strange that you check if `$seat[$first]['name']` is empty and then assign it (empty value) to `$name`

to help us fix your code please add `$data->seat_layout` and `$request->seat_id` values

Comment: @user3837868 give me please example `$data->seat_layout` and `$request->seat_id` values

Comment: Column_name : seat_layout , Type : longtext, Value : [{"style":"position: relative;","id":0,"name":"A1","profile":""}

Comment: and example of  `$request->seat_id` value please ?

Comment: all the data in one column seat_layout and  seat_no is=0

Answer (score 1):

I changed empty to !empty now is working fine

```
$name = !empty($seat[$first]['name']) ? $seat[$first]['name'] : $seat_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that either $no['name'] or $key is an array and not a string. Please check them both.

You should convert the array into a string by using a serialization method or create your own.

Comment: ya it is array so how i can do this?